# dynamically choose between two labels for the Display Name in mvc ef

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using Entity Framework, MVC. How can I dynamically change between two labels for one data field (based on data retrieved from another database about the same vehicle)? Ideally I would like my Model class to have something like this in it (this is pseudocode and is not expected to compile):

```
[Display(Name = "resCatalyst", ResourceType = typeof(VehiclesModelResource))]
    public string Catalyst { get; set; }
...
public void SetElementDisplayName(bool DieselOlderThan2009)
    {
        if (DieselOlderThan2009)
        {
            Catalyst.SetDisplayName(Name = "resNMHCCatalyst", ResourceType = typeof(VehiclesModelResource));
        }
        else
        {
            Catalyst.SetDisplayName(Name = "resCatalyst", ResourceType = typeof(VehiclesModelResource));
        }
    }
```

I did think of changing the label in the cshtml file like this:

```
@if(Model.vltDataOne.FuelType == "D" && Model.vltDataOne.VehicleYear >= 2009)
            {
                <p>
                        <b> @Html.LabelFor(model => model.testObd.Catalyst, @DTResource.resNMHCCatalyst) </b>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.testObd.Catalyst) 
                </p>
            }
else
            {
                <p>
                        <b> @Html.LabelFor(model => model.testObd.Catalyst, @DTResource.resCatalyst) </b>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.testObd.Catalyst) 
                </p>
            }
```

But I am responding to a business rule and I really think it should be in the Model, not the View. Is there any way to move this logic to the Model? Thanks for any ideas/insights.

Comment: I suggest you create a ViewModel class that implements the behavior you need.  Then reference it on your View.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make it a read-only property of your model whose return value is decided by the other properties:

Note: Assumptions about your code follow. Re-jig this as you need to:

```
public class YourModel {
    public string FuelType { get; set; }
    public int VehicleYear { get; set; }

    public string CatalystLabelText {
        get {
            return (this.FuelType == "D" &&
                   this.VehicleYear >= 2009) ? _resNMHCCatalyst : _resCatalyst;
        }
    }
}
```

Your view then (correctly) becomes a view.. and not a decision maker:

```
<b> @Html.LabelFor(model => model.testObd.Catalyst, Model.CatalystLabelText) </b>
```

Comment: That's great! Because FuelType and VehicleYear are in another model class, and come from another database, I will use the class that holds a pointer to each. The concept will be what you laid out here. It was really bugging me having logic in the view.

Comment: Glad I could help. Generally with MVC (generally == always) when you have logic in your view.. you have something fundamentally wrong with your design. Its good that you're asking questions about this sort of thing!